# How do I add firestore document Id to my model and subsequently to the array?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have a struct "Order" that contains a field called orderId:

```
protocol OrderSerializable {
    init?(dictionary:[String:Any])
}

struct Order {
    var orderId: String
    var status: Int
    var currentTotal: Double

    var Dictionary:[String : Any] {
        return [
            "orderId": orderId,
            "status": status,
            "currentTotal": currentTotal
        ]
    }
}

extension Order : OrderSerializable {
    init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        guard let orderId = dictionary["orderId"] as? String,
        let status = dictionary["status"] as? Int,
        let currentTotal = dictionary["currentTotal"] as? Double

        else { return nil }

        self.init(orderId: orderId, status: status, currentTotal: currentTotal)
    }
}
```

I need to add the firestore document Id to the orderId field in the model array i.e. "ordersArray". How would I go about doing that?

This is my query code so far and I have indicated the line that I need:

```
orderRef.getDocuments() {
            querySnapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else { return }
                for document in documents {
                    let orderDictionary = document.data() as [String : Any]
                    let order = Order(dictionary: orderDictionary)
                    // Here I want to append the firestore documentId to order.orderId before appending it to the array
self.ordersArray.append(order!)

                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.ordersTableView?.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

**Different error**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Modify your extension to accept the `documentId` as an additional parameter, and pass this to the created Order object.

```swift
protocol OrderSerializable {
    init?(dictionary:[String:Any], id: String)
}
extension Order : OrderSerializable {
    init?(dictionary: [String : Any], id: String) {
        guard let status = dictionary["status"] as? Int,
        let currentTotal = dictionary["currentTotal"] as? Double
        else { return nil }

        self.init(orderId: id, status: status, currentTotal: currentTotal)
    }
}
```

Then, when you create each order, pass the `documentId` as the `id` parameter.

```swift
orderRef.getDocuments() {
            querySnapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else { return }
                for document in documents {
                    let orderDictionary = document.data() as [String : Any]
                    let order = Order(dictionary: orderDictionary, id: document.documentId)
                    self.ordersArray.append(order!)

                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.ordersTableView?.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
```

Alternatively, you could have stored the `orderId` directly in the document itself, so that it would be passed in along with the dictionary, avoiding the need for using `documentId`.

Comment: When I remove the orderId from the dictionary in the extension as you suggested, I get a "Use of unresolved identifier 'Id'" associated with the "orderId: Id" in self.init

Comment: @BVB09 Did you copy and paste that error message exactly? It looks like you're using a capital `I` for `id`. Just copy and paste the extension I wrote.

Comment: I cannot use id since it is protected by Xcode. But I am making an elementary mistake here that I cannot get past. I attached a screenshot in the original question.

Comment: @BVB09 Ah I see, I forgot that you also need to update the protocol. See my updated answer.

Comment: Hmm. Now I am getting "Use of undeclared type" associated with the extension Order: OrderSerializable